# How to add a height to the near by div?

Tags: css, html

```
<div style="float:left;">
    <div id="one" style="float:left;background-color:yellow;width:300px;height:100%;">
    </div>
    <div id="two" style="float:left;background-color:green;width:300px;font-size:35px;">Test
    </div>
 </div>
```

I have no text in id=one, but I have text in id=two.
In this case, I would like to get the same div height for id=one as of id=two.
How to achieve this? Someone help me!!
I have tried adding height:100% for id=one, but it doesn't work.

If possible someone tell me how to achieve this without using display:table properties.

Comment: If you use heigh: 100%, then your parent elemnt should have some strict height (in px for example).

Comment: If you are confident to use a javascript library you can use jQuery Match Height: https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height . It can be as easy as including it in your html <head> and adding: data-mh="my-group" to each div you want to match.

Comment: Thanks for your comment guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) add `display:flex` to the container

2) remove `height:100%` from the child

```html
<div style="float:left;display:flex;">
    <div id="one" style="background-color:yellow;width:300px;">
    </div>
    <div id="two" style="background-color:green;width:300px;font-size:35px;">Test
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This was the thing I really expected. Thank you so much @Danield !!

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way.

```css
.row {
  display: flex; /* equal height of the children */
}

.col {
  flex: 1; /* additionally, equal width */
  
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad omnis quae expedita ipsum nobis praesentium velit animi minus amet perspiciatis laboriosam similique debitis iste ratione nemo ea at corporis aliquam.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, using `display: table` to parent div and `display: table-cell` to children divs.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test2">I have soem text here</div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  display: table;
  color: #fff;
}

.test1 {
  min-width: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  background: red;
}

.test2 {
  min-width: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  background: blue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4tmfvp5o/

Comment: From the question: "*without using display:table properties.*"

Comment: Sorry, didnt see this one

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery plugin makes this problem very easy to solve: https://github.com/dubbs/equal-height

Then simply use:

```
<div style="float:left;">
    <div class="Col" id="one" style="float:left;background-color:yellow;width:300px;height:100%;">
    </div>
    <div class="Col" id="two" style="float:left;background-color:green;width:300px;font-size:35px;">Test
    </div>
 </div>
```

and

```
$('.Col').equalHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using flexbox. I've given you a [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/MaryBartlett/cxj8ubbt/1/). You'll see that if you add a width: 5px to the element with class of `one` that the div is the same height.

This is an invaluable resource on [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

but note it might not be compatible [for all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: Thanks for your help @Mary